# Android SREC_JNI compilation error

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, speech-recognition

I am trying to compile SREC_JNI code in Eclipse (Windows 7), I got the code from here https://github.com/arthurv/srec

I am getting the following error

```
C:\android-ndk-r8c\ndk-build.cmd all 
"Compile++ thumb : srec_jni <= android_speech_srec_MicrophoneInputStream.cpp
jni/srec_jni/android_speech_srec_MicrophoneInputStream.cpp:26:23: fatal error: utils/Log.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/srec_jni/android_speech_srec_MicrophoneInputStream.o]          Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

I would like to know where the utils folder is located and how to compile this SREC code.

Answer (score 2):

This project is a fork of a component of Android OS. It should be built from the [Android system tree](https://android.googlesource.com/) and not with NDK as a standalone project.

You can find 
[utils/Log](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/a0db308c3d62301ae41b2e2bcf295c4ee4c7b08e/include/utils/Log.h) in platform/frameworks/native repository:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native
```